# MFi Certification for Bluetooth Classic Device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, mfi

I am developing an app (for my company) which need to connect with our own hardware device. Our Hardware Device is based on **Bluetooth Classic** (BL).

When I am trying to connect my device to my app then that device is not shown in my list because I am using Core Bluetooth and I know if I want to connect my device which is based on Bluetooth Classic then I need **MFi certification**.

When I read Apple Documents I understand the complete process of MFi certification.

**Now my question is:-**

1. After completion of MFi Certification process do I need to use **special authentication chip** in my device which is already designed or what would be the change in my device when I will certify from MFi (is there any change in my already build hardware device)?

**What will happen after MFi Certification. How can apple identify my device.**

2. What did it cost to certify with MFi?

Comment: Yes, to use legacy Bluetooth profiles, such as SPP, you will need it to be MFi certified and manufactured by an [MFi manufacturing licensee](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQNDA.action). This requires specific hardware support, including an MFi chipset installed on the board. It is highly unlikely that you can retrofit MFi compatibility to existing hardware. You need to join the MFi program to get cost details,  but [this article](https://appleinsider.com/articles/14/02/07/apple-lowers-mfi-lightening-licensing-fees-paving-way-for-more-affordable-ios-accessories-) suggests $4 per device.

Comment: Thanks, First I will go for MFi Certification and after certification process will complete then apple with provide the specific hardware (MFi Chipset) to inbuilt in my hardware device ?

Comment: MFi manufacturing licensees can purchase MFi chipsets through an Apple MFi authorised component distributor. Your company needs to join the MFi program as a non-manufacturing member in order to get access to the information you need to design your hardware

Comment: Thanks again ... what about that products which is already in market .... 10,000+ products is already in market ... I am developing iOS app for those product also... so is there any solution for those products ...

Comment: Devices which support Bluetooth Low Energy do not require mfi support. Devices that use hands free or audio profiles do not require mfi support. Any other device must include the mfi chip to work with iOS. Your app can only support specific mfi hardware that is registered against your developer membership

Comment: (BL Classic + BLE) both is in my device and that is already in mark because that is easily control with Android now its time to build iOS App. I need to communicate with both BLE and BL Classic at a time. But now I understand that I need MFi certification with Hardware MFi Chipsets. So my iOS App will not work with that device which is already in market.

Comment: Am I right ? @Paulw11

Comment: Correct.  You can communicate with the device using BLE, but you cannot communicate with classic bluetooth (e.g. SPP). If you were building new hardware then you would probably just use BLE.  You can use L2CAP if you need large data transfer.  That way you can avoid MFi

Comment: I want to do some audio based task from my device ... like play music when single tap button on my device or call someone by siri if double tap button on my device. So for doing this I need MFi Certification from Apple or is there any alternative way ?

Comment: If the device uses HFP or A2DP for audio and AVRCP for remote control or BLE for user controls then you don't need Mfi

Comment: wow... means I can transfer music or audio with BLE ? means after pairing with BLE from my app I can play music and control HFP and A2DP ? I found that BLE is not for A2DP and HFP ... :(.. this is my last problem.

Comment: No, HFP and A2DP are classic bluetooth, but your device does not need to be MFi certified to use these profiles - Refer to the [MFi FAQ](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-2).  The device using these profiles just appears as an available audio route in iOS.  What I meant in my previous comment is that if you use HFP/A2DP/AVRCP *and/or* BLE your device doesn't need to be MFi certified

Comment: As I know Without MFi I am not able to connect with BL Classic within my app. So after BLE Pairing within my app can I use A2DP/HFP ?

Comment: A2DP/HFP pairing must be performed by the user using the Settings app on their device.

Comment: That is the problem .... if I am doing this then everything is ok.. but company says he want to know when when BL Classic is disconnected .. try to connect automatically when device is in range. First time user will pair with that device then BL Classic and BLE connection will automatically form when device is in range if iPhone bluetooth is on.

Comment: If the device is paired as an audio device and it comes into range then iOS can reconnect automatically; The same as when you get back into your car and the phone automatically connects to your stereo.  Your app can't find out about it unless it is in the foreground though; It can subscribe to audio route changes.

Comment: ok.. now I got it.

Comment: so ... can u give me a reason why my device is not automatically paired. When I off my device and after that when I on it ... it still not paired ? Thanks for giving me your precious time ... I got my solution.

Comment: Does it use one of those standard profiles?  Is it paired in device settings?  Does it advertise and attempt to reconnect to the last connected device?

Comment: A2DP/HFP,  yes, yes....  when my iPhone bluetooth is on after first time pairing and connected ... it is not automatically connected for next time ... but In case of android after first pairing and connection.... if I off the android phone bluetooth and on it again then its try to connect and connected but if I just of the device bluetooth and on it again then device is not connected ..

Comment: @Paulw11 ... can u help me regarding this.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237839/can-siri-be-invoked-after-taping-on-my-ios-app-button

Comment: As I previously ask about auto Bluetooth Classic connection is not working ... actually the problem is ... my device is not a master device ... and we are not making our device to master because we want to connect our one devise to second device as well as connected to my phone .. have u any solution about this ?

Comment: @Paulw11 I need your help in this question .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324164/bt-of-device-a-is-auto-disconnected-with-iphone-when-device-a-try-to-connect