# Can Siri be invoked after taping on my iOS App button?

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts, siri-remote

**I want to invoke Siri from my app**. My app is also connected to BLE device and I want to open Siri from my BLE device as well as.

So, How can I do this ? **Is it possible to invoked siri from my iOS App ?**

Comment: You can't invoke Siri from an app.  I don't believe that you can invoke Siri from a BLE device either.  You can do it via a legacy Bluetooth device that implements the AVRCP profile

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there any alternative option .... in my device BL Classic and BLE both is available.. BL Classic is paired via iPhone Setting and BLE is connected via Core Bluetooth... now I know which button is pressed in my Device By BLE. So Siri Invoke is one of the main feature ... so any alternative solution ... ? I am able to listing music from my device ... pause and play etc...

Comment: I am using HFP and A2DP Profile Only...

Comment: This thread indicates that you can do it using BLE by implementing HID over GATT - https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/11191/how-to-launch-siri-from-nrf51.  According to the HFP spec, you can issue the `AT+BVRA` to the phone and it will invoke Siri

Comment: We are using HFP or SCO for invoking google assistants in android... can SCO work for iOS ? Can u send me a link by which I can understand Bluetooth terms in depth like HID, SCO, HFP, AVRCP, GATT, AT+BVRA ?

Comment: The chances are, whatever you are doing for Android devices will invoke Siri on an iOS device.  The HFP specification is here - https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=292287

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion... finally it’s worked  ... last confusion in ... App Store accepts my App or not ... because my app is totally based on my device ☹️

Comment: @Paulw11... I want to invoke siri by saying 'hey siri' but this in only work with iPhone Microphone not with my BT Microphone (My Device Microphone) ... is it possible to do... now I am able to invoke siri by pressing button but not with audio :(