# BT of Device "A" is auto disconnected with iPhone when Device "A" try to connect to Device "B"

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My Device "A" is connected with my iPhone through BT and then by using nRF Connect BLE is also connected with Device "A".

Through nRF Connect I am initiating the pillion connection between Device "A" and Device "B".

So finally Pillion is activited and working properly for 10 Second and then Device "A" is disconnected with iPhone (Only BT).

But Pillion is working fine.

So the problem in why BT of Device "A" is disconnected when Device "A" try to connect with Device "B".

**In case of android this is working fine and Device "A" is Conncected with Andorid as well as Device "A" is connected with Device "B". This problem occure with iPhone Only**

When Device "A" try to connected with Device "B" then iOS triger BT Disconnect Command because Device "A" is already connected with iPhone. I am sure this by checking bluetooth logs of iPhone.

We are using different channel in FW (fermwere) for establish connection between them.

EDIT----

**I also found that when Device "A" is connected with iPhone and Device "A" is connected with Device "B" then just after 2 Sec if I paly the music and busy the port in between iPhone And Device "A" connection then BT of my iPhone is not disconnected.**

Comment: Can device A be connected simultaniously to various devices?

Comment: @Larme Yes, Even In case of android this is working fine and Device "A" is Conncected with Andorid as well as Device "A" is connected with Device "B". This problem occure with iPhone Only.

Comment: Can you maybe post the log you are referring to?

Comment: Name of the Bluetooth IC is CC2564 TI.