# How can I get IPA of any app which is available on App Store ? (Older way is not working)

Tags: ios, app-store, ipa

I want to download IPA of other App. I got some solution on stackoverflow but that is older and not properly working at this time.

There is a Mac App called Apple Configurator 2. With the help of this application I got IPA of some applications but only few.

But I want to download IPA of Specific Application. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: I use iMazing to get the IPA from my device

Comment: @Paulw11 Again thanks for help. Is full version is compulsory for getting IPA of any application ?

Comment: No. You can use the free version

Comment: @paulw11.. please give some solution on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56324164/9400369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download an iOS application IPA file from the AppStore you have to download / buy an app on your iPhone.

```
1. Now download the Apple Configurator 2 (AC2) app on your Mac then
connect your iPhone to the Mac and connect the AC2 with your AppleID
account.
2. Right click on your connected device in AC2 and select Add->Apps...
3. Once selected app / apps will be downloaded, AC2 will present a modal dialog with actions to select. Do not do anything right now.
4. Open Finder and go to a folder "~/Library/Group Containers/K36BKF7T3D.group.com.apple.configurator/", inside
Caches->Assets->TemporaryItems->MobileApps you will find a folders
which contains downloaded apps
5. Copy an IPA files to other location because originals will be deleted
6. Select "Stop" action in AC2
```

Comment: On your mac: 1. In terminal go to root by `cd ..` 2. Run the command `chflags nohidden ~/Library` to make everything permanently visible 3. select `Library` from the Finder's `Go` menu 4. You'll see `Group Containers` folder.